# Android flavors, Gradle sourceSets merging

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I try to make an application for multiple partners and for each partner a test and prod version. For each flavors I create a specific folder with res/values in it like the documentation said.

My gradle file look like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
            versionCode 1
            versionName 1
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

    productFlavors {
        prodPARTNER1 {
            applicationId "com.PARTNER1"
        }

        testPARTNER1 {
            applicationId "com.PARTNER1.test"
        }
        prodPARTNER2{
            applicationId "com.PARTNER2"
        }

        testPARTNER2{
            applicationId "com.PARTNER2.test"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        testPARTNER2 {
            res.srcDirs = ["testPARTNER2/res", "prodPARTNER2/res"]
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicatorLibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
}
```

I want for a test version to take res folder of the prod version (like this I not duplicate resources for both version) and merge it with the test version.
The problem is :

`Error:Error: Duplicate resources:` 
`C:\...prodPARTNER2\res\values\strings.xml:string/app_name,`         `C:\...testPARTNER2\res\values\strings.xml:string/app_name`

Any idea ? It's not possible to merge too res folder for the same flavors ?

EDIT : I use gradle v 1.1.0 and android studio v 1.1.0 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning:** this approach has changed a little bit on [Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#flavor_dimensions)

Use `productFlavors` for each partner app and define a build type `test` for test builds.

```
productFlavors {
    partner1 {
        applicationId "com.partner1"
    }

    partnerN {
        applicationId "com.partnerN"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
      // use defaults
    }
    release {
      // the 'prod' version, use defaults
    }
    test {
      // config as you want!
        applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        versionNameSuffix " Test"
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

You can use mix and match source folders as the [Android Plug-in for Gradle](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html) shows:

> To build each version of your app, the build system combines source code and resources from:
>
> - `src/main/` - the main source directory (the default configuration common to all variants)
> - `src/<buildType>/` - the source directory
> - `src/<productFlavor>/` - the source directory

**Edit:** This user guide is another source of help: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

**Edit 2:** according to the link above:

> Additional sourcesets are also created for each variants:
>
> - `android.sourceSets.flavor1Debug`
>   Location `src/flavor1Debug/`
> - `android.sourceSets.flavor1Release`
>   Location `src/flavor1Release/`
> - `android.sourceSets.flavor2Debug`
>   Location `src/flavor2Debug/`
> - `android.sourceSets.flavor2Release`
>   Location `src/flavor2Release/`

Then, you can use `/src/partner1Test/` to define resources specifics to `partner1` flavor AND `Test` build, that is a `partner1Test` build variant.

Comment: Great I don't have to create 2 flavor for one partner ! but how can I have differents resource (and merged with prod version) for my test version ? Cause src/<buildType>/ become src/test and will be used for all partner, it's not partner specific right ?

Comment: For example I want to change app_name in string.xml for prod it's MyPartner1App and for test it's MyPartner1TestApp how can I do this ?

Comment: @jaumard comment1, question2: Yes, `src/test` will be used for all partners when building `test` build type, it's not partner specific.

Comment: @jaumard comment2: just define `string/app_name` again in `src/partner1Test` folder

Comment: @jaumard comment1, question1: using source sets like I showed in the answer, it is done automatically: ex: `string/app_name=App` in src/main can be redefined to `string/app_name=AppSpecific` in src/specific

Comment: Thanks !!! I test to create a folder "partner1Test" with "test" as buildType and it's working !  :)

Comment: Hi, I tried to add the new "obfuscated" build type, that simply is a release buildType with minifyEnabled=true. The problem is that Android Studio gives me the error "Default activity not found". Any ideas?